# Not installed react-leaflet library

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

When I trying to import a library "react-leaflet", I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/propTypes/map.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'leaflet' in 'D:\PycharmProjects\adminora\node_modules\react-leaflet\lib\propTypes'
@ ./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/propTypes/map.js 5:15-33
@ ./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/Map.js
@ ./node_modules/react-leaflet/lib/index.js
```

**EDIT:** My package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.36",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.8.1",
  }
```

Comment: plz provide your package.json file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the dependency packages aswell, try using

`npm install leaflet prop-types react react-dom react-leaflet`

Comment: I had only installed `npm i leaflet-react` and got the same error. I then `npm i leaflet` and it worked fine :D

Answer (score 2):

delete node_modules folder  and package-lock.json  file and try below commands.

```
npm install
npm install leaflet react-leaflet --save
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help me

Comment: how you create that project ? have you used npm create-react-app youAppName ?

Comment: Dude, you are a life-saver! Works perfectly now! Thanks!

Comment: You need install *leaflet* `npm install leaflet`